# Запятая на стыке двух союзов

Tags: запятые

Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты.

Каков смысл этого предложения?

Что сказал врач? Только то,что больному нужен покой?

Или врач еще сказал: если вы не хотите тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты?

Answer (score 1):

Врач сообщил всю информацию полностью. Соответственно, попробуем подобрать для ее передачи подходящую форму.

1) При отсутствии придаточной части это выглядело бы так: "Врач сказал, что больному нужен покОй и мы должны выйти из палАты. Здесь выделяются две интонационные фразы (однородные придаточные  интонационно соответствуют однородным членам).

2) Казалось бы, такое оформление следует сохранить и при наличии придаточной части: "Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты".

3) Однако интонация такой структуры противоречит реальной: фактически сообщение распадается на две самостоятельные части с явно обозначенной паузой после слова "покой", поэтому здесь нужна запятая:"Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты".

4) Получается, что  всю полученную от врача информацию мы не можем оформить в виде однородных придаточных, поэтому мы делим сообщение на две части. Первая половина текста передается в виде косвенной речи  (СПП 1), далее союз И присоединяет (СПП 2) с придаточным условия. Таким образом, вторая часть сообщения представлена не как косвенная речь, а как понимание ситуации ее участниками.

Answer (score 1):

Можно только догадываться, что сказал врач.

**Вариант 1. Все слова принадлежат врачу.**

А. *Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой и мы должны выйти из палаты.*

Б. *Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой и, если мы не хотим тревожить его, должны выйти из палаты.*

В. *Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты.*

**Вариант 2. Не все слова принадлежат врачу.**

А. *Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и мы должны выйти из палаты.*

Б. *Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и, если мы не хотим тревожить его, должны выйти из палаты.*

В. *Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты.*

Мы видим, что варианты В одинаковы. Точно ответить на вопрос, что сказал врач, по этому предложению нельзя. Смысл восстанавливается из контекста. Если для автора этот вопрос принципиален, нужно оформить текст по-другому.